# PHP if/else form

Tags: php

I am trying to create a form where if you fill in a number like 11 you get a response with a color type. I know that I have to change $tulp, but I don't know what to do.

```
<form name= "gemiddelden" action= "" method="post">
  <p>Geelzweem (%): <input type="text" name="getal1"/></p>
  <p><input type="submit" name="Bepaal" value="Bepaal"/></p>
  </form>

$tulp = date("H");

if($tulp == 10) {
  echo("Lichtgeel");
}
else if($tulp >10 && $tulp <20)
{
  echo("Geel");
}
else if($tulp >20 && $tulp <30)
{
  echo("Zon geel");
}
else if($tulp >30 && $tulp <40)
{
  echo("Diep Geel");
}
else if($tulp >40 && $tulp <50)
{
  echo("Zwavel Geel");
}
else if($tulp >50 && $tulp <60)
{
  echo("Intens Geel");
}
else if($tulp >60 && $tulp <70)
{
  echo("Verzadigd Geel");
}
else if($tulp >70)
{
  echo("Dit mag niet");
}

else {
  echo("Error");
```

Comment: But `$tulp` is always the current hour. Where does the form play in this? What have your tried to connect them up?

Comment: `$tulp = $_POST['Bepaal'];`? `$tulp = $_POST['getal1'];`?

Comment: change you last `else if` in `else`

Comment: If I set $tulp to $tulp=10; It will always give the color that has the value 10, no matter what code you fill in

Comment: you need to use if isset use this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp

Comment: Thank you for the help, I needed to change $tulp to $tulp = $_POST['getal1'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to google translate Geelzweem represent the shade of yellow. Then the echoed texts are different shades. I am guessing that you need to display a color based on the input in the getal1 field. In that case you need to change the line

```
$tulp = date("H");
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST["getal1"])) {
    $tulp = $_POST["getal1"];
} else {
    // some default value here
    $tulp = 20;
}
```

Also, although the standard says that it is not mandatory, it is best practice to specify the action of the form

```
<form name= "gemiddelden" action= "SOME URL HERE" method="post">
```

Answer (score -2):

Needed to change $tulp to $tulp = $_POST['getal1'];